# Isolate nodejs scripts inside the physical or logical folder

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, virtualbox, isolatedstorage, chroot

I am trying to find a solution where people (users) will be able to write/upload/run their own nodejs scripts inside the same server machine. The biggest problem for me is to make their projects enough isolated from each other, so one user can not get access to others' files via 'fs' (for example) or a different way. All scripts going to be run under the same Linux user.

Scanning the internet for some days and still not found any appropriate solution. Is it possible at all?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: There are numerous online Node.js playgrounds. Would that work? If not, do you have a Linux machine(or VM or EC2 instance in AWS) that these users already have isolated (and authenticated) access to?

Comment: @jarmod yes, it will be something like a playground, but very specific. I have Linux machine, but users don't have (and can't have) their respective Linux users in the system. Projects can be shared between lots of users or even guests. But the code running inside one project should not have an access to other projects' files and folders.

Comment: Not sure how you're going to do this without writing a custom application if you can't leverage individual Linux users. How do you intend for them to access the Linux machine, if not SSH as independent users? Wonder if there's some kind of Node.js variant of Jupyter Notebooks that would allow users to maintain independent notebooks of JavaScript code.